# Extracting Nested List-Dictionaries to Pandas Series in a DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, normalization

I have a pandas dataframe that I have extracted from a JSON file for breweries I'm interested in. most of these columns are as nested list of dictionaries. However two columns 'hours' and 'memberships' are being problematic.

I'd like to extract the 'hours' column into 7 columns "Mon_Hours","Tue_hours"...'Sun_Hours'.
I have tried and tried to figure this out but these two columns are proving challenging.

Here is a link to the initial data: https://www.coloradobrewerylist.com/wp-json/cbl_api/v1/locations/?location-type%5Bnin%5D=404,405&page_size=1000&page_token=1

and here is my code:

```
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import json
from datetime import datetime


### get the data from the Colorado Brewery list
url = "https://www.coloradobrewerylist.com/wp-json/cbl_api/v1/locations/?location-type%5Bnin%5D=404,405&page_size=1000&page_token=1"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
data=response.json()

### convert results to table
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
brewdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['results'])
#brewdf

############################################
#### CLEAN UP NESTED LIST-DICT COLUMNS #####
############################################

## cleanup dogs column
dogs = pd.json_normalize(brewdf['dogs'])
dogs2 = dogs.squeeze()
dogsdf = pd.json_normalize(dogs2)
dogsdf = dogsdf.drop(columns =['id','slug'])
dogsdf = dogsdf.rename(columns={'name':'dogs_allowed'})
#dogsdf

## cleanup parking column
parking = pd.json_normalize(brewdf['parking'])
parking = parking.rename(columns = {0:'Parking1',1:'Parking2',2:'Parking3'})
a  = pd.json_normalize(parking['Parking1'])
b  = pd.json_normalize(parking['Parking2'])
c  = pd.json_normalize(parking['Parking3'])
parkcombo = pd.concat([a,b,c],ignore_index=True, axis=1)
parkcombo = parkcombo.rename(columns = {2:'P1',5:'P2',8:'P3'})
parkcombo['parking_type'] = parkcombo['P1'].map(str) + ',' + parkcombo['P2'].map(str) + ',' + parkcombo['P3'].map(str)
parkcombo['parking_type'] = parkcombo['parking_type'].str.replace(",nan",'')
parkdf = parkcombo['parking_type'].to_frame()
#parkdf

## cleanup food type column
food = pd.json_normalize(brewdf['food_type'])
food
food = food.rename(columns = {0:'Food1',1:'Food2',2:'Food3',3:'Food4',4:'Food5',5:'Food6'})

a  = pd.json_normalize(food['Food1'])
b  = pd.json_normalize(food['Food2'])
c  = pd.json_normalize(food['Food3'])
d  = pd.json_normalize(food['Food4'])
e  = pd.json_normalize(food['Food5'])
f  = pd.json_normalize(food['Food6'])

foodcombo = pd.concat([a,b,c,d,e,f],ignore_index=True, axis =1)
foodcombo

foodcombo = foodcombo.rename(columns = {2:'F1',5:'F2',8:'F3',11:'F4',14:'F5',17:'F6'})
foodcombo['food_type'] = foodcombo['F1'].map(str) + ',' + foodcombo['F2'].map(str) + ',' + foodcombo['F3'].map(str) + ',' + foodcombo['F4'].map(str)+ ',' + foodcombo['F5'].map(str) + ',' + foodcombo['F6'].map(str)
foodcombo['food_type'] = foodcombo['food_type'].str.replace(",nan",'')
fooddf = foodcombo['food_type'].to_frame()
#fooddf

## cleanup patio column
patio = pd.json_normalize(brewdf['patio'])
patio = patio.rename(columns = {0:'P1',1:'P2',2:'P3'})

a  = pd.json_normalize(patio['P1'])
b  = pd.json_normalize(patio['P2'])
c  = pd.json_normalize(patio['P3'])

patiocombo = pd.concat([a,b,c],ignore_index=True, axis =1)
patiocombo

patiocombo = patiocombo.rename(columns = {2:'P1',5:'P2',8:'P3'})
patiocombo['patio_type'] = patiocombo['P1'].map(str) + ',' + patiocombo['P2'].map(str) + ',' + patiocombo['P3'].map(str) 
patiocombo['patio_type'] = patiocombo['patio_type'].str.replace(",nan",'')
patiodf = patiocombo['patio_type'].to_frame()
#patiodf

## clean visitor type column
visitor = pd.json_normalize(brewdf['visitors'])
visitor
visitor = visitor.rename(columns = {0:'V1',1:'V2',2:'V3'})

a  = pd.json_normalize(visitor['V1'])
b  = pd.json_normalize(visitor['V2'])
c  = pd.json_normalize(visitor['V3'])

visitorcombo = pd.concat([a,b,c],ignore_index=True, axis =1)
visitorcombo
visitorcombo = visitorcombo.rename(columns = {2:'V1',5:'V2',8:'V3'})
visitorcombo['visitor_type'] = visitorcombo['V1'].map(str) + ',' + visitorcombo['V2'].map(str) + ',' + visitorcombo['V3'].map(str) 
visitorcombo['visitor_type'] = visitorcombo['visitor_type'].str.replace(",nan",'')
visitordf = visitorcombo['visitor_type'].to_frame()
#visitordf

## clean tour type column
tour = pd.json_normalize(brewdf['tour_type'])
tour
tour = tour.rename(columns = {0:'T1',1:'T2',2:'T3',3:'T4'})

a  = pd.json_normalize(tour['T1'])
b  = pd.json_normalize(tour['T2'])
c  = pd.json_normalize(tour['T3'])
d  = pd.json_normalize(tour['T4'])

tourcombo = pd.concat([a,b,c,d],ignore_index=True, axis =1)
tourcombo
tourcombo = tourcombo.rename(columns = {2:'T1',5:'T2',8:'T3',11:'T4'})
tourcombo['tour_type'] = tourcombo['T1'].map(str) + ',' + tourcombo['T2'].map(str) + ',' + tourcombo['T3'].map(str) + ','+ tourcombo['T4'].map(str)
tourcombo['tour_type'] = tourcombo['tour_type'].str.replace(",nan",'')
tourdf = tourcombo['tour_type'].to_frame()
#tourdf

## clean other drinks column 
odrink = pd.json_normalize(brewdf['otherdrinks_type'])
odrink
odrink = odrink.rename(columns = {0:'O1',1:'O2',2:'O3',3:'O4',4:'O5',5:'O6',6:'O7',7:'O8',8:'O9'})

a  = pd.json_normalize(odrink['O1'])
b  = pd.json_normalize(odrink['O2'])
c  = pd.json_normalize(odrink['O3'])
d  = pd.json_normalize(odrink['O4'])
e  = pd.json_normalize(odrink['O5'])
f  = pd.json_normalize(odrink['O6'])
g  = pd.json_normalize(odrink['O7'])
h  = pd.json_normalize(odrink['O8'])
i  = pd.json_normalize(odrink['O9'])

odrinkcombo = pd.concat([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i],ignore_index=True, axis =1)
odrinkcombo

odrinkcombo = odrinkcombo.rename(columns = {2:'O1',5:'O2',8:'O3',11:'O4',14:'O5',17:'O6',20:'O7',23:'O8',26:'O9'})
odrinkcombo['odrink_type'] = odrinkcombo['O1'].map(str) + ',' + odrinkcombo['O2'].map(str) + ',' + odrinkcombo['O3'].map(str) + ','+ odrinkcombo['O4'].map(str) + ','+ odrinkcombo['O5'].map(str)+ ','+ odrinkcombo['O6'].map(str)+ ','+ odrinkcombo['O7'].map(str)+','+ odrinkcombo['O8'].map(str)+','+ odrinkcombo['O9'].map(str)
odrinkcombo['odrink_type'] = odrinkcombo['odrink_type'].str.replace(",nan",'')
odrinkdf = odrinkcombo['odrink_type'].to_frame()
#odrinkdf

## clean to-go column 
togo = pd.json_normalize(brewdf['togo_type'])
togo
togo = togo.rename(columns = {0:'TG1',1:'TG2',2:'TG3',3:'TG4',4:'TG5'})

a  = pd.json_normalize(togo['TG1'])
b  = pd.json_normalize(togo['TG2'])
c  = pd.json_normalize(togo['TG3'])
d  = pd.json_normalize(togo['TG4'])
e  = pd.json_normalize(togo['TG5'])

togocombo = pd.concat([a,b,c,d,e],ignore_index=True, axis =1)
togocombo
togocombo = togocombo.rename(columns = {2:'TG1',5:'TG2',8:'TG3',11:'TG4',14:'TG5'})
togocombo['togo_type'] = togocombo['TG1'].map(str) + ',' + togocombo['TG2'].map(str) + ',' + togocombo['TG3'].map(str) + ','+ togocombo['TG4'].map(str) + ','+ togocombo['TG5'].map(str)
togocombo['togo_type'] = togocombo['togo_type'].str.replace(",nan",'')
togodf = togocombo['togo_type'].to_frame()
#togodf

## clean merch column 
merch = pd.json_normalize(brewdf['merch_type'])
merch
merch = merch.rename(columns = {0:'M1',1:'M2',2:'M3',3:'M4',4:'M5',5:'M6',6:'M7',7:'M8',8:'M9',9:'M10',10:'M11',11:'M12'})

a  = pd.json_normalize(merch['M1'])
b  = pd.json_normalize(merch['M2'])
c  = pd.json_normalize(merch['M3'])
d  = pd.json_normalize(merch['M4'])
e  = pd.json_normalize(merch['M5'])
f  = pd.json_normalize(merch['M6'])
g  = pd.json_normalize(merch['M7'])
h  = pd.json_normalize(merch['M8'])
i  = pd.json_normalize(merch['M9'])
j  = pd.json_normalize(merch['M10'])
k  = pd.json_normalize(merch['M11'])
l  = pd.json_normalize(merch['M12'])

merchcombo = pd.concat([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l],ignore_index=True, axis =1)
merchcombo

merchcombo = merchcombo.rename(columns = {2:'M1',5:'M2',8:'M3',11:'M4',14:'M5',17:'M6',20:'M7',23:'M8',26:'M9',29:'M10',32:'M11',35:'M12'})
merchcombo['merch_type'] = (merchcombo['M1'].map(str) + ',' + merchcombo['M2'].map(str) + ',' + merchcombo['M3'].map(str) + ','+ merchcombo['M4'].map(str) + ','
                            + merchcombo['M5'].map(str) + ',' + merchcombo['M6'].map(str)+ ',' + merchcombo['M7'].map(str) + ',' + merchcombo['M8'].map(str)
                            + ',' + merchcombo['M9'].map(str)+ ',' + merchcombo['M10'].map(str)+ ',' + merchcombo['M11'].map(str)+ ',' + merchcombo['M12'].map(str))
merchcombo['merch_type'] = merchcombo['merch_type'].str.replace(",nan",'')
merchdf = merchcombo['merch_type'].to_frame()
#merchdf

### clean description column
brewdf['description'] = brewdf['description'].str.replace(r'<[^<>]*>', '', regex=True)
#brewdf

### replace nan with null
brewdf = brewdf.replace('nan',np.nan)
brewdf = brewdf.replace('None',np.nan)
brewdf

cleanedbrewdf = brewdf.drop(columns = {'food_type','tour_type','otherdrinks_type','articles','merch_type','togo_type','patio','visitors','parking','dogs'})
mergedbrewdf = pd.concat([cleanedbrewdf,dogsdf,parkdf,fooddf,patiodf,
                         visitordf,tourdf,odrinkdf,togodf,merchdf,],ignore_index=False,axis=1)
mergedbrewdf

### remove non-existing
finalbrewdf = mergedbrewdf.loc[(mergedbrewdf['lon'].notnull())].copy()
finalbrewdf['lon'] = finalbrewdf['lon'].astype(float)
finalbrewdf['lat'] = finalbrewdf['lat'].astype(float)
finalbrewdf
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction for the hours and memberships columns? Also, is there a more efficient way to look through these different columns? They have different nested list-dict lengths which I thought might prevent me from writing a function.

Comment: where are hours and membership in the json data? what is the path to them?

Comment: I think the OP is trying to extract week info and hours info from the`created date/modified date` field. Example `"created_date":"2014-02-13T23:51:23-07:00","modified_date":"2017-10-20T14:18:53-06:00"` from the json file link provided above.

Comment: Maybe you should convert `created_date/modified_date` into `datetime` using `pd.to_datetime` and extract week and hours info, then try processing taking only week and hour columns

Comment: Moving data to column names (& back) is called (un)pivoting. (Doing this is usually an anti-pattern best done as final output & by a gui not DB.) (Beware "pivot table" is sometimes used to mean "association/join/bridge/many-to-many/etc table".)

Comment: @sammywemmy  'hours' and 'memberships' are their own columns. They come in like this: 

"hours":[{"close":{"day":0,"time":"2300"},"open":{"day":0,"time":"1400"}},{"close":{"day":1,"time":"2300"},"open":{"day":1,"time":"1400"}},{"close":{"day":2,"time":"2300"},"open":{"day":2,"time":"1400"}},{"close":{"day":3,"time":"2300"},"open":{"day":3,"time":"1400"}},{"close":{"day":5,"time":"0000"},"open":{"day":4,"time":"1400"}},{"close":{"day":6,"time":"0000"}

AND 
"memberships":[{"id":501,"slug":"colorado-brewers-guild","name":"Colorado Brewers Guild"}]

Comment: @philipxy I was moving to columns and back because pd.json_normalize( ) was giving me integers as column names which was causing errors in pandas with cols like dogsdf[0]. Realize my cleaning sections approaches are not best practice. Wondering what is the best approach with these nested list of dicts.

Comment: I tried doing list comprehension testing on dogs using this method starting at the 4:10 mark (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTJ3AQfRpN4) but the error I get is "'float' object is not iterable"

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments.

Comment: Rearranging DB designs to get rid of nested tables or values with structures is called DB normalization to 1NF. Notions of ["1NF"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097) basically all say, collapse a group of tables or columns with names that differ by parameters into one table with a column per parameter. Then further rearranging to split up tables to get rid of certain problems called update anomalies is called DB normalization to higher normal forms,